# Multiple variable expansion modifiers in the same expression

Tags: bash, array, variable-substitution

Why does the following idiom not work in bash 4.1.0?

```
if [[ "${FUNCNAME[*]:1/$FUNCNAME/}" != "${FUNCNAME[*]:1}" ]]
```

Here it is in context...

```
function isCircularRef_test () {
  #
  ### Seems like this should work but it does not.
  ###   if [[ "${FUNCNAME[*]:1/$FUNCNAME/}" != "${FUNCNAME[*]:1}" ]]; then ...
  ### It appears to fail silently and exit the script so neither 'then' nor
  ### 'else' branch executes.
  ### Storing the array into a temporary string variable works. Why necessary?
  #
  printf "%s\n" "VERSION #1"
  local _fna="${FUNCNAME[*]:1}"
  if [[ "${_fna/$FUNCNAME/}" != "${_fna}" ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "IS circular reference"
  else
    printf "%s\n" "IS not circular reference"
  fi
  #
  printf "%s\n" "VERSION #2"
  if [[ "${FUNCNAME[*]:1/$FUNCNAME/}" != "${FUNCNAME[*]:1}" ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "IS circular reference"
  else
    printf "%s\n" "IS not circular reference"
  fi
}
```

Output is...

```
VERSION #1
IS not circular reference
VERSION #2
```

Comment: Can't help you there, you are mistaken that I am a bash aficionado.

Comment: What happens if you use @ rather than *?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of shell parameter expansion says that the syntax of substitution is:

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
```

Notice that the first part is a `parameter`, not another expression containing a parameter expansion. The same goes for all the other expansion modifiers. You have to do it in two steps:

```
func1=${FUNCNAME:1}
if [[ ${func1/$FUNCNAME/} != ${func1} ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, it doesn't like using the `:index` and the `/pattern/` modifiers in the same expression:

```
./t.sh: line 19: FUNCNAME[*]: 1/isCircularRef_test/: division by 0 (error token is "/")
```

Comment: In general, you can't use multiple variable expansion modifiers in the same expression.

Comment: @Barmar - If you'll put this into an answer, I'll accept it. If you can find any references in the bash documentation or elsewhere of this behavior, that would make it more useful to others too. Thanks!