# Detecting circular references in bash 4.1.0

Tags: bash

The following function is called as the first line in every other function in order to handle optional debugging, context sensitive help, etc. Because of this, calling a function that in turn calls another function can (usually will) result in a circular reference.

How can the circular reference be avoided without losing functionality?

```
function fnInit () {
  ###
  ### on return from fnInit...
  ###   0   implies "safe to continue"
  ###   1   implies "do NOT continue"
  ###
  #
  local _fn=
  local _msg=
  #
  ### handle optional debugging, context sensitive help, etc.
  #
  [[ "$INSPECT" ]]  && { TIMELAPSE= ...; }
      ### fnInit --inspect
  #
  [[ "$1" == --help       ]]  && { ... ;   return 1; }
      ### fnInit --help
  #     :
  #     :
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bailout if function fnInit() (e.g the current function - ${FUNCNAME[0]}) also appears higher up in the function call stack.

In the resultant version below...

- $_fna is a string containing a space-separated list of the function names in the function call stack starting with the function that called this function (level 1 and up).
- The idiom `"${_fna/${FUNCNAME[0]}/}"` subtracts current function name from $_fna.
- The comparison `[[ "${_fna/${FUNCNAME[0]}/}" != "${_fna}" ]]` returns true(0) if the result of that subtraction is the same as the original (thus, nothing was subtracted)
- The list processing control operator `&&` says to execute the following command if and only if the preceding command (the `[[ ... ]]`) had a return code of true(0).
- The curly braces around the return (`{ return 0; }`) are optional here since there is only one command to execute. However **they are mandatory** in all other cases so I usually put them in for consistency. Without them, because of operator precedence, something like `[[ ... ]]  && dosomething; return 0` would execute `dosomething` only if `[[ ... ]]` is true, as expected. ***But would always execute `return 0`.*** Bash would read it as...

  ```
      [[ ... ]]  && dosomething
      return 0
  ```

Do `fnInit()` processing only once per function call...

```
function fnInit () {
  ###
  ### on return from fnInit...
  ###   0   implies "safe to continue"
  ###   1   implies "do NOT continue"
  ###
  local _fna="${FUNCNAME[*]:1}"; [[ "${_fna/${FUNCNAME[0]}/}" != "${_fna}" ]]  && { return 0; }
    ### Detect circular reference
    ###   Is function in the function call stack more than once?
    ###
    ### Seems like the following should work but it does not...
    ###   if [[ "${FUNCNAME[*]:1/$FUNCNAME/}" != "${FUNCNAME[*]:1}" ]]; then ...
    ###       It appears to fail silently and exit the script so neither 'then'
    ###       nor 'else' branch executes.
    ### Why?
    ###   per http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186942/27437...
    ###   In general, you can't use multiple variable expansion modifiers
    ###   in the same expression. –  Barmar
    ### 
    ### Solution:
    ###   Store the array into a temporary string variable.
    ###
  #
  local _fn=
  local _msg=
  #
  ### handle optional debugging, context sensitive help, etc.
  #
  [[ "$INSPECT" ]]  && { TIMELAPSE= ...; }
      ### fnInit --inspect
  #
  [[ "$1" == --help       ]]  && { ... ;   return 1; }
      ### fnInit --help
  #     :
  #     :
  return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually that's done by checking and setting a state variable (a flag). Something like...

```
function fnInit
{
    [[ -z ${this_init_state} ]] || return 0
    this_init_state=1

    # rest of your code
}
```

(If your initialization function is in a separate module then source that module with the dot command.)

Comment: Don't forget to add `this_init_state=` before the real `return` (or every `return`, if applicable). Or maybe you can use `trap … RETURN`.